# WordPress Redirect on Name Change

Tags: wp-config

I changed the domain name in my WordPress options menu because I was changing the domain name of my site. Now, however, the page never loads. What can cause this and/or how can I revert it back to the previous domain?

Comment: What about getting into the cPanel's phpMyAdmin and then to the site's database, and then to the `wp_options` table. Then edit the two `option_name`'s `option_value`s: (1) siteurl, and (2) home? ([Details](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#Changing_the_URL_directly_in_the_database))

Comment: yes that fixed it. Now to figure out how to make it work with the new domain...

Comment: When moving Wordpress to a new domain it is needed to search and replace all reference of the old domain in the database with the new domain. See [Moving Wordpress When Your Domain_Name or URLs Change](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#When_Your_Domain_Name_or_URLs_Change)